# ionic native http post call is not supporting responseType as blob for pdf download from as WebService

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native-http

I am using ionic5 with Angular.
My API returns pdf as Blob object.
I am able to get Blob response when using Angular Http(which works on browser)

```
let headers =
  new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/pdf',
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'localhost'
  });
  return this.httpClient.post(
         apiURL, 
         JSON.stringify(myBodyParamsObj), 
         {headers: headers, responseType: 'blob'}
     );
```

But I am not able to get response when using ionic native http(which is required to use to run app in device due to CORS issue when using Angular Http). Tried like below-

```
   this.nativeHttp.setDataSerializer("raw"); // Tried other options like json etc. but none works
   this.nativeHttp.post(apiURL, params, { 'Authorization': myAuthHeaderObj, 'Content-Type': 'application/json',  'Accept': 'application/pdf', responseType: 'blob'});
```

Also tried `this.nativeHttp.sendRequest` but didn't get success.

Please help

Comment: What is and what is not happening? Do you see a request at the server-side? Do you have any logging or errors on the client or the server? Android or iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Finally it worked using below piece of code-

```
if(requestType == 'BLOB'){
      nativeHttpPromise =  this.nativeHttp.sendRequest(
        apiURL,
        {
          method: 'post',
          data: params,
          headers: { Authorization: authHeader },
          responseType: "blob",
          timeout: 5000
        }
      );
     }
```

So basically , instead of using nativeHttp.post, nativeHttp.sendRequest() willwork as it accepts responseType='blob'

Comment: nativeHttp means is it 'cordova-plugin-advanced-http' plugin?